# Cannot run games in fullscreen after installing USB graphics adapter

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, fullscreen, direct3d

I purchased a USB 3.0 graphics card to get around my graphic card's limitation that only allows two active monitors at once. It works perfectly fine and now I'm able to use three monitors at once.

However, since I installed it, my computer won't run any games in full screen mode, even though I'm using a screen that is connected directly to my internal graphics card.

Prototype 2, for instance, gives me the following message:
[image]

```
FEHLER: Direct3D konnte nicht initialisiert werden.
Lesen Sie die README-Datei und stellen Sie sicher,
dass Ihr System die minimalen Anforderungen erfüllt.
```

In English:

```
ERROR: Direct3D could not be initialized.
Please read the README file and make sure
that your system meets the minimum requirements.
```

Some games just crash silently. Jazz Jackrabbit 2 even gave me a bluescreen.

Unplugging the adapter doesn't help. It worked all fine before I first connected the adapter. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe installation of the new graphics card overwrite some drivers. What does dxdiag.exe claim?

Comment: What is dxdiag.exe?

Comment: It is the [direct X diagnostic tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/run-directx-diagnostic-tool).  

( [Direct3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct3D) is part of direct X. )

Comment: System tab: http://share.raptilic.us/2014-11-05_21-20-07.png
The display I would like to use for gaming: http://share.raptilic.us/2014-11-05_21-20-28.png

Comment: It is showing "No problems found". That is a good thing but not the item I was hoping to see. It also shows DDI version 10. I think this means you have directX version 10. Do all card support this? Or does the newers USB card only support DX9?  (grasping at straws here).

Comment: It does say that I have DirectX 11 on the system tab. But also, the display connected via the adapter is not the one I want to use to play, but disconnecting the adapter doesn't fix the problem.